# (unity)InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

Hello I want migration unity project version from 5.0.2 to 2020.x.x

when did directly migration to 2020.x.x I did run into a problem with expection

"InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible."

So I did try migration Sequentially unity5 -> V2017 -> V2018 was working well

But when I migration v2019 I did run into a problem with  same expection

this code is causing problems area

```
[System.Serializable]
public class BookStruct 
{ 
    public int ID; 
    public int[] PageComposition; 
    public int PageCount; 
    public string Name; 
    public int CoverPageID; 
    public int CategoryID; 
    public Dictionary<SystemLanguage, TextDataTemplate> dicTextData; 
    public int[] RecommendBookList; 
    public int MarketingMark; 
    public string RecommendAge; 
    public int Priority; 
    public bool FreeAtNow; 
} 

  /*  public static string BinaryStringFormatter(object target)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(ms, target);

    return BitConverter.ToString(ms.ToArray()); // not here!
} */

public static object BinaryDeserialize(byte[] data)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    return formatter.Deserialize(ms); //here!
}
```

bottom code is before code

```
 switch (Application.platform)
    {
        case RuntimePlatform.Android:
            filepath = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/"+bookname;
            break;
        default:
            filepath = "file://" + Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + bookname;
            break;

    }
    
    Debug.Log("파일 경로 확인  => " + filepath);

    using (WWW www = new WWW(filepath))
    {
        while (!www.isDone)
        {
            yield return true;
        }

        TextAsset t = www.assetBundle.mainAsset as TextAsset;

        book = (BookStruct)BK_Function.BinaryDeserialize(t.bytes);

        www.assetBundle.Unload(true);

        iBook.iPageCount = book.PageComposition.Length;

        Debug.Log(book.dicTextData[SystemLanguage.Korean].Description);
        Debug.Log("pagecount : " + book.PageCount + " // pageComposition.Length : " + book.PageComposition.Length);
    }
```

Also,I did Debug.log file path and result is

" file://C:/unitySource/singlebook/Assets/StreamingAssets/B12_2_Cat.unity3d"

and Bookstruct is

""

Please help me (:

Comment: book struct is => [System.Serializable];
public class BookStruct
{
    public int ID;
    public int[] PageComposition;
    public int PageCount;
    public string Name;
    
    public int CoverPageID;
    public int CategoryID;
    
    public Dictionary<SystemLanguage, TextDataTemplate> dicTextData;

    public int[] RecommendBookList;
    public int MarketingMark;
    public string RecommendAge;
    public int Priority;

    public bool FreeAtNow;
}

Comment: Wow that is a huge jump in Unity versions over several years! A lot of changes happened in the meantime .. maybe you should rather to incremental upgrades and fix any appearing errors bit by bit

Comment: In general [**STOP using `BinaryFormatter` at all!**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) Rather use XML or JSON or similar formats

Comment: Also instead of the **obsolete** `WWW` rather use [`UnityWebRequest.Get`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html)

Comment: in general `BitConverter.ToString` returns something different than you might expect .. it will give you a string where each given byte is represented as hexadecimal string .. that is not the same as the actual bytes written to a binary file ...

Comment: @derHugo I'm sorry i did upload another code... I modified new code..!